# How to specify levels in python logging module?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, structlog

I need two handlers. One for file logging and another one for stream logging in the console. I need to specify levels for each handler. Notice that my levels are going to be something like the following ones.

Stream Handler --> INFO

File Handler --> WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL

Here is my code.

```py
    # Create a custom logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('DBMQ')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('./data/file.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Now, it has to operate like this:

```
logger.debug('hey') # Nothing should happen
logger.info('hey') # only stream handler should log this message
logger.warning('hey') # only file handler should log this message but the stream does too
logger.error('hey') # only file handler should log this message but the stream does too
logger.critical('hey') # only file handler should log this message but the stream does too
```

I need to disallow the stream handler from logging the `warning`, `error`, and `critical` logging levels. Is there any way to filter this handler?

Comment: Whats the result you are getting with your code?

Comment: The file handler works well, but the stream handler logs those last three levels. I just want it to log the `INFO` level only.

Comment: Log levels are always minimum levels. INFO means "log INFO or higher". Scenarios where you want a log to contain some logs, but not some more important logs are hard to construct.

Comment: @schwobaseggl exactly. I'm looking for a way to log a certain level, but as you mentioned, It does a level or higher..!!

Comment: How is this structlog related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own Handler:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('DBMQ')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class MyStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno == self.level:
            super().emit(record)

stream_handler = MyStreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('./data/file.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works properly, but the stream handler still logs a message with `warning` level. Now, both error and critical are disabled for Stream handler which is good.

Comment: It works as you described for me. Did you change anything from my example?

Comment: I just added my File handler. Tried again and works well. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a common way? Is there any way to add this class to a `.conf` file? I want to write up a configuration file and use `fileConfig()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The "level" system does not work to as disable/enable single "levels".
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

The "level" is a single integer value. If the message's level is over logger/handler level, it will be showed. Just that simple.

If you need another logic the only way is implement you own handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Lufftre's answer here, but I don't like the idea of creating a whole class just for this, so I'm basically patching the StreamHandler's emit function into a lambda function, like so:

```
chs = logging.StreamHandler()
chs.setLevel(logging.INFO)
chs.semit = chs.emit # You have to "clone" original emit, as there is no super()
chs.emit = lambda record: chs.semit(record) if record.levelno == chs.level else None
logger.addHandler(chs)
```

I think it looks cleaner. If you want multiple handlers working in this way, then you can first define a function that is this lambda and then patch the `emit` with that function object.

```
# Set up new emit
nemit = lambda record, sh: sh.semit(record) if record.levelno == sh.level else None

# Create first handler
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
ch.semit = ch.emit 
ch.emit = lambda record: nemit(record, ch)

# Create second handler
chs = logging.StreamHandler()
chs.setLevel(logging.INFO)
chs.semit = chs.emit
chs.emit = lambda record: nemit(record, chs)

logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(chs)
```